# The required steps to migrate our old web-apps to Code Igniter framework?

Tags: php, web-applications, codeigniter, migration

I want to know the simplest (in general) steps required to migrate our old web applications (both, back end and front end) to Code Igniter Framework.
Please share your ideas / experience in this !

The old web pages doesn't have any framework at all. They are just just basic procedural PHP codes.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: If you're introducing a new framework, migration isn't simple.

Comment: The old web apps are just procedural PHP codes, with no existing framework.

Comment: There are no simple yet detailed and complete steps! It will be different from legacy app to legacy app...

Comment: Hi, as long as it contains the most important steps, it is enough for me. I am not asking for complete codes, just quick bulleted points list consisting the required steps (in general).

Comment: Any help please? Some general implementation steps that I will have to do. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to tell for sure without seeing your code, but my general opinion is that unless the old code is an absolutely excellent, high-quality, well-documented masterpiece, then the best thing is probably to **rewrite the whole thing**.

- Old PHP code is unlikely to conform with a modern framework's structure and preferences, and is likely to use deprecated practices
- Old HTML code is unlikely to match modern standards (CSS....)

I dare say that in the vast majority of cases, rewriting from scratch is less expensive than trying to fit this old wine into new skins.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have suggested, there's no set answer to this question.  One things for sure though, to some extent each port will be a rewrite.  Some apps more than others and that largely depends on how you're current apps are coded.

That being said, this is generally how I would approach this...

1. Make sure that everyone on your team spends some time getting familiar with CodeIgniter and how applications are setup using their framework.  It may be worth writing a new app in CI first before porting existing ones just to get accustomed to how everything should be structured.
2. On an case by case basis, assess the bloat in your existing app and/or things that should be modified.  You're basically going to be doing a rewrite for each app.  So it would be a good idea to determine what you really need for the app to function in CI and whatever minor changes you can make for less code, easier rewrite etc.  Every app has those areas that you meant to get to but just never had the time to get to it.  Well now's your chance.  This will likely save you time in the rewrite.
3. Come up with a game plan by getting everyone who's involved with porting the apps together to discuss what's going to need to be done.
4. Start writing and communicate with one another new things you've learned along the way.